# Why do I get different results on the server for the same codes?

Tags: server, python-requests

I set the same url and cookies for `requests.get()` to get a web page.

I run these codes on my own computer. I get the response shows that I have already logged in. But when I run the same codes on the server, I get the response shows that I haven't logged in.

I want to know why the same codes get different results. How can I log in using the same codes on the server?

Comment: The session held for you (for those cookies) by the server can be tied to an IP address, among other things.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I get the new cookies tied to the server by 'requests.post()' and I use this cookies to solve  problem. Thank you again.